# Autowire a bean within Spring's Java configuration

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to use Spring's `@Autowired` annotation within a Spring configuration written in Java?

For example:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration{

   @Autowired 
   DataSource datasource;

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource(){
       return new dataSource();
   }

   // ...

}
```

Obviously a DataSource interface cannot be directly instantiated but I directly instantiated it here for simplification.  Currently, when I try the above, the datasource object remains null and is not autowired by Spring.

I got `@Autowired` to work successfully with a Hibernate `SessionFactory` object by returning a `FactoryBean<SessionFactory>`.

So my question specifically: is there a way to do that with respect to a `DataSource`?  Or more generally, what is the method to autowire a bean within a Spring Java Configuration?

I should note I am using Spring version 3.2.

Comment: Why would you need to autowire it _there_?

Comment: I was simply trying to convert an xml configuration file into a Java one.  I thought since I can reference the bean by id in xml, why shouldn't I utilize the autowire annotation on it within a Java configuration file?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you need a reference to the `DataSource` bean within the same `@Configuration` file, just invoke the bean method.

```
@Bean
public OtherBean someOtherBean() {
    return new OtherBean(dataSource());
}
```

or have it autowired into the `@Bean` method

```
@Bean
public OtherBean someOtherBean(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new OtherBean(dataSource);
}
```

The lifecycle of a `@Configuration` class sometimes prevents autowiring like you are suggesting.

You can read about Java-based container configuration, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/java.html). [This section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/java/configuration-annotation.html#beans-java-further-information-java-config) goes into detail about how `@Configuration` classes are proxied and cache the beans that the define, so that you can call `@Bean` annotated methods but only every get back one object (assuming the bean is singleton scoped).

Comment: That's interesting, it works exactly has you have described.  Why is that?  Can you point me to any Spring documentation that talks about this precise issue?  Thank you very much for the answer by the way.

Comment: @Avanst See the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-configuration-annotation).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, today I spent a couple of hard hours looking for the similar problem caused by injecting members into configuration class.

Comment: What if `DataSource` is an interface?  For example it extends spring-data's CrudRepository interface.  How would you autowire in `dataSource` then?

Comment: @heez `DataSource` is an interface (`java.sql.DataSource`). I don't understand your concern.

Comment: Updated link for the documentation referenced in the comment from @SotiriosDelimanolis: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java

Comment: Why is this answer ideal? If you call the bean method directly, it will always return a new object. And the new object will not be a Spring managed bean. Autowiring a parameter to a method is ideal. But there is another solution which I have given below. Simply assign the value of new object to your instance variable in the bean method. This way when the bean is initialized, your instance variable will have the value of the bean. Can someone please explian why my answer has been given a negative rating?

Comment: @Varun It won't return a new object, see the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/java/configuration-annotation.html#beans-java-further-information-java-config: _This is where the magic comes in: All `@Configuration` classes are subclassed at startup-time with CGLIB. In the subclass, the child method checks the container first for any cached (scoped) beans before it calls the parent method and creates a new instance._

Answer (score -2):

For completeness sake: Yes it is technically possible to use @Autowired annotation in spring @Configuration classes, and it works the same way as for other spring beans. But the accepted answer shows how the original problem should be solved.

Answer (score -3):

maybe you can use constructor to inject some bean from other configuration file to your configuration，while @Autowired may not work correct in the configuration file

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  private DataSource dataSource;

  public AppConfig(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public OtherBean otherBean(){
    return new OtherBean(dataSource);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

beans configured with @Configuration class can't be autowired ,

So you cannot use @Autowiring and @configuration together