# Inject Spring repository into Spring @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to read my db to load a custom setting inside my Spring @Configuration class.

I have something like:

```
 @Configuration
    public MyConfigClass implements ApplicationContextAware{

    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public ServerSession serverSession() throws Exception {
          ServerSession serverSession = new ServerSession(urlGateway, useSsl, hostGateway, portGateway);
      return serverSession;
    }
```

I should read parameters from DB instead from property file. I know that I can't @Inject my repository directly into this class, but there is a trick or something that permit me to do this or at least make a query on db?

I'm using Hibernate + Spring + Spring Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer injecting the necessary dependencies as a parameter. Using `@Autowired` in a field looks unnatural to me in a `@Configuration` class (just using stateful fields, as configuration is supposed to be stateless). Just provide it as a parameter for the bean method:

```
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public ServerSession serverSession(MyRepo repo) throws Exception {
    repo.loadSomeValues();
    ServerSession serverSession = new ServerSession(urlGateway, useSsl, hostGateway, portGateway);
    return serverSession;
}
```

This might require using `@Autowired` itself at method level, depending on the Spring version:

```
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
@Autowired
public ServerSession serverSession(MyRepo repo) throws Exception {
    repo.loadSomeValues();
    ServerSession serverSession = new ServerSession(urlGateway, useSsl, hostGateway, portGateway);
    return serverSession;
}
```

**See also:**

- [Autowire a bean within Spring Java configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28748366/1199132)

Answer (score 0):

Autowiring and DI work in @Configuration classes.  If you're experiencing difficulties then it may be because you're trying to use the injected instance too early in the app startup lifecycle.

```
@Configuration
public MyConfigClass implements ApplicationContextAware{
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repo;

    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public ServerSession serverSession() throws Exception {
        // You should be able to use the repo here
        ConfigEntity cfg = repo.findByXXX();

        ServerSession serverSession = new ServerSession(cfg.getUrlGateway(), cfg.getUseSsl(), cfg.getHostGateway(), cfg.getPortGateway());
        return serverSession;
    }
}

public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<ConfigEntity, Long> {
}
```

Comment: I yet tried the same thing you wrote but unfortunately repo remains null.